# wordpress google maps resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, google-maps

i know this is a problem with so many topics here on stack overflow, i find them during my search, however i guess this one is slightly different.

I' using a plugin on wordpress that allows me on a page using tabs to change content.
In an page i have a double tab, which one showing a different google map embed code.
As you may already have figured out my problem, when i change tab the center of the map appears on the left top corner.

I found javascript and jquery solutions, but this is a wordpress page, i can't use that there, so, how can i solve this on my wordpress website?

Thank you!

Edit:

```
    [tab name="X"]

&nbsp;

<iframe width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.pt/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=pt-BR&amp;geocode=&amp;q=40.654471,-7.914153&amp;aq=&amp;sll=41.236676,-8.332331&amp;sspn=0.593802,1.234589&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=40.654471,-7.914153&amp;spn=0.018721,0.038581&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.pt/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=pt-BR&amp;geocode=&amp;q=40.654471,-7.914153&amp;aq=&amp;sll=41.236676,-8.332331&amp;sspn=0.593802,1.234589&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=40.654471,-7.914153&amp;spn=0.018721,0.038581&amp;t=m&amp;z=14" target="_blank" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Exibir mapa ampliado</a></small>

[/tab]
[tab name="Y"]

&nbsp;

<iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="http://maps.google.pt/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=pt-BR&amp;geocode=&amp;q=40.741339,-7.730044&amp;aq=&amp;sll=40.654483,-7.914145&amp;sspn=0.00936,0.01929&amp;g=40.654483,-7.914145&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=40.741339,-7.730044&amp;spn=0.018696,0.038581&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<small><a style="color: #0000ff; text-align: left;" href="http://maps.google.pt/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=pt-BR&amp;geocode=&amp;q=40.741339,-7.730044&amp;aq=&amp;sll=40.654483,-7.914145&amp;sspn=0.00936,0.01929&amp;g=40.654483,-7.914145&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=40.741339,-7.730044&amp;spn=0.018696,0.038581&amp;t=m&amp;z=14" target="_blank">Exibir mapa ampliado</a></small>

[/tab]
[end_tabset]
```

Comment: Are you saying that the map's center glitches, or that the map container glitches, or both? Have an example of this site?

Comment: the map's center. after reload page, when i change tabs, the map of the second tab (the one i select), the map center goes to the left corner of the map container.

Comment: Some tab implementations are pretty volatile - they destroy and recreate HTML. When this happens, google map may not be entirely aware of its geometry during the tab-switch-reconstruction phase. Anyhow, fixes in these cases are usually JavaScript that manually reset the gmap center and force a redraw.  For you, next step will be to show us this malfunctioning HTML in its viewable entirety. Problem is too specific to offer a generic solution.

Comment: i updated the code in the initial post.
as i said this is inside a page of wordpress.
the [tabs] has to do with the wordpress plugin i use to change the code inside, in this case, the maps.

That's i asked here and not on the other topics like this one on stack overflow.

The only option i'm seeing is to apply a javscript plugin to use on pages/posts of my website.
But what should i use there to force a redraw?

Comment: good question but why dont you just go change it with Javascript?

Comment: so i should install plugin ADR suggested and implement javascript inside the wordpress page?

Comment: We need to look at this in the wild. Can't just guess how to fix it based on this embed code / shortcodes. :/

Comment: But then what i can show you?
This is a simple article page in wordpress pp19dd, what part should i show you then?

Answer (score 1):

> I found javascript and jquery solutions, but this is a wordpress page, i can't use that there

I personally use a plugin called "Inline Javascript Plugin" which allows you to type javascript code directly inside a Wordpress page/post